# Json string not valid when I created an array and converted into json string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I create a couple dictionaries and add them into an `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[myDictionary setObject:@"test_name" forKey:@"option_name"];
[myDictionary setObject:@"15" forKey:@"option_id"];

NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[myDictionary2 setObject:@"test_name2" forKey:@"option_name"];
[myDictionary2 setObject:@"16" forKey:@"option_id"];

NSMutableArray *myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[myArray addObject:myDictionary];
[myArray addObject:myDictionary2];
```

When I print `myArray`, I get this:

```
(
  {
     "option_id" = 15;
     "option_name" = "test_name";
  },
  {
    "option_id" = 16;
    "option_name" = "test_name2";
  }
)
```

When I try to create a JSON string with this array, it is not valid. 
The JSON string is like this:

```
 {"function":"myFunction", "parameters": {"result":[{"question_name":"my question","question_id": "15", "options_array":[

    {
     "option_id" = 15;
     "option_name" = "test_name";
    },
    {
    "option_id" = 16;
    "option_name" = "test_name2";
   }]}


   ]}
 }
```

Where I am making the mistake? Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: How are you converting your array into JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be converting your `NSMutableArray` into a JSON string in some strange way. This works perfectly for me:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"myArray JSON string: %@", jsonString);
// log: myArray JSON string: [{"option_id":"15","option_name":"test_name"},{"option_id":"16","option_name":"test_name2"}]
```